# Problem while updating

Tags: 11.10, updates

When I try to do the system update I get this:

```
Failed to fetch http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/language-pack-en/language-pack-en_11.10+20111121_all.deb 404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/language-pack-gnome-en/language-pack-gnome-en_11.10+20111121_all.deb 404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nautilus/libnautilus-extension1_3.2.1-0ubuntu3.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nautilus/nautilus-data_3.2.1-0ubuntu3.1_all.deb 404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nautilus/nautilus_3.2.1-0ubuntu3.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/banshee/banshee_2.2.1-1ubuntu2_i386.deb 404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/banshee/banshee-extension-soundmenu_2.2.1-1ubuntu2_i386.deb 404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntuone-client/libsyncdaemon-1.0-1_2.0.0-0ubuntu2.2_i386.deb 404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntuone-client/ubuntuone-client_2.0.0-0ubuntu2.2_all.deb 404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntuone-client/python-ubuntuone-client_2.0.0-0ubuntu2.2_all.deb 404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/banshee/banshee-extension-ubuntuonemusicstore_2.2.1-1ubuntu2_i386.deb 404  Not Found
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Which version are you updating?

Comment: version 11.10...

Comment: Are you connected to internet?

Try: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 3):

I've faced a similar problem. The problem was that package repository mirror on `rs.archive.ubuntu.com` was not available. So I did the following to choose another mirror:

- Open the `sources.list` file with your favourite text editor, e.g.

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
  ```
- Change the repostory URLs from `rs.archive.ubuntu.com` to another, e.g. `us.archive.ubuntu.com`
- Save the file
- Run a package list update, e.g.

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```

  This should run without errors.

Comment: Good suggestion to change mirrors. For a GUI installation you can change the mirror in the "Software Sources" system application as well, also accessible via the System updater.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs when the packages you are trying to download are now superseded by newer versions.

To fix the problem, just refresh your software sources and try to update again.

You can do that in a terminal with

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```